# Attempt to index nil with humanoid

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

I tried to apply a Humanoid Description on a player that joined the game but the output gives an error: "Attempt to index nil with humanoid". Heres is the code.

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(Player)
    Player.Character.Humanoid:ApplyDescription(game.ServerStorage.HumanoidDescription)
end)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wait for the Character to load in the game. Before applying the HumanoidDescription.

```lua
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(Player)
    Player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(character)
       wait()
       character:WaitForChild("Humanoid"):ApplyDescription(game.ServerStorage.HumanoidDescription)
    end)
end)
```

Comment: but this returns a other error: Humanoid::ApplyDescription() DataModel was not available

Comment: @takezo try the updated version. I added the WaitForChild.

Comment: 'Infinite yield possible on 'Players.Me:WaitForChild("Character")'

Comment: @takezo check again. That means you have to use wait before running that line.